# Vanishing of a Galois cohomology of a pro-$p$ group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology

Suppose $G$ is a pro-$p$ group and $M$ is a discrete $p$-primary module **not necessarily finite**. Suppose the $p$-cohomological dimension of $G$ is $n$. Can one conclude 
$$
H^n(G,M) \neq 0?
$$

This is fairly easy to see when $M$ is finite..